# Magic 8-ball program

Tags: java

I have an assignment for my Java class to program a Magic 8-ball. It is supposed to generate a random number for the response, contain a "while(true)" statement, and a switch statement for the replies. This is what I have so far. I can't seem to figure out how to work the "while(true)" statement in without it repeating infinitely.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String question;
    int retry;
    int q1;

    System.out.print("What is your question for the Magic 8-bit 8-ball? ");
    question = input.next();
    System.out.print(process());
    /*This is where I am having the problem. How do I work a "while(true)" in
     * to where this won't infinitely repeat?
     */

    }

public static int process() {
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    int random = rand1.nextInt(9);
    int ans = random;


    switch (ans) {
        default: System.out.println("Does not compute!! Error! Error!");break;
        case 1: System.out.println("The answer is.............. 42");break;
        case 2: System.out.println("To get to the other side!!!");break;
        case 3: System.out.println("Out of memory! Try again!");break;
        case 4: System.out.println("Who do you think I am, IBM's Watson?");break;
        case 5: System.out.println("Danger Will Robinson!! Danger!!");break;
        case 6: System.out.println("What do you think?");break;
        case 7: System.out.println("Fatal error.....nahhh just kidding");break;
        case 8: System.out.println("Well, this is fun....NOT!");break;
        case 9: System.out.println("Um...... 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000?");break;
       }
      return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some kind of condition that will end your program. Have that be the condition of your while loop, or else check that condition in the while loop and use a `break` statement.

Comment: what is the while loop supposed to do? Your question makes no sense

Comment: Your title is useless. It says nothing about the problem or question.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, the point of a `while (true)` loop is to be infinite, unless you add a `break` statement in it.

```
while (true) {
   doStuff();
   // if someCondition is true, this will exit the loop
   if (someCondition)
       break;
}
```

Note that this is equivalent to

```
do {
    doStuff();
} while (!someCondition);
```

or

```
boolean someCondition = false;
while (!someCondition) {
    doStuff();
}
```

It is usually preferrable to **not** have an infinite loop (`while (true)` for example) and have an explicit condition instead. Some exceptions exist, for example if the condition is complicated to express or if you want to break the loop at a particular position of the loop and not at the beginning or at the end :

```
while (true) {
    doStuff();
    if (someCondition)
        break;
    doSomeOtherStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the many possible ways:

- Create a a char and assign it to `'Y'` (i.e. `char continueLoop = 'Y'`).
- Use this to control the while statement (i.e. `while(char == 'Y')` ).
- Ask the user for input and process the input (i.e. `System.out.println("Continue? Y/N")` and then use `Scanner` to read the input and assign it to continueLoop.

You can create something similar using booleans.